# How to fix error "Value of '3/23/2019 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'."

Tags: c#, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a form for appointment with a couple of textboxes and asks for a follow up visit (datetimpicker). I have set the datetimepicker with this code so date before today will be unabled:

```
private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nextvisitchanged = true;
            dateTimePicker2.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
            dateTimePicker2.CalendarForeColor = Color.DarkTurquoise;
        }
```

After the information is saved, it will load in the datagridview on the same form. I have the datagridview in cellclick weherein it populates the textboxes with data from the database (this is for viewing). I am getting the error "Value of '3/23/2019 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'" if the next visit date is already past the date today. I know this is because of the dateTimePicker.Mindate = DateTime.Now; Is there a way that this error could be fixed? Or I am doing it the wrong way?

This is my code for the datagridview cellclick:

```
private void per_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            httb.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            wttb.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            tptb.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            subtb.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            assessmenttb.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            pltb.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            imid.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            dateTimePicker2.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Side note: Don't use the index to get a value of a particular cell, always use the column name. If you or somebody else changes the layout of the DataTable and inserts a new column between e.g. index 3 en 4, your application will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Well you won't be able set the value unless to change the `MinDate` value, however it is for just showing the selected date not for editing it, right? so why don't you show it on a label or textbox instead of DateTimePicker?

```
label1.Text = per.Rows[persondt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,

Issue: The set **MinDate = DateTime.Now** was taking the Current time as well.

e.g (2023/03/22 08:00:00)

And I tried to set the **.Value** = *2023/03/22 00:00:00*

Which will throw an error due to the time, Solution:

```
MinDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

this Will return *2023/03/22 00:00:00*